# Excel 2016: Conditional Formatting: Highlight row if cell value is in list

Tags: conditional-formatting, excel-2016

Excel 2016 Conditional Formatting question:

I have two tabs, `Data` and `List`:

- Data has 5 columns. Column A is the item ID number, the others have
  project related data.
- List has 1 column. This is a list of ID numbers
  that have been processed.

Here is the question: 
How do I highlight the rows for processed ID numbers? I want to be able to add ID numbers to List as I process more rows. I want to see processed items in Data in green highlight, because green makes the boss happy!

Looking forward to your input!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order for others to better assist you, you should provide some sample ID number so we know if there are purely numeric or could be alphanumeric which may or may not have an impact on the final answer. You should also share what you have tried so far or what you think the solution may be as this is not a free code writing website. Having that said, I am happy to assist you even if you are unable to come up any solution at this stage. Just provide some sample ID number to help me kick start your task :) Also, please add **`#Conditional-Formatting`** to your tags.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `VLOOKUP` to find the value in the `List` sheet. An error means the value doesn't exist. Since you want to know if it *does* exist, just invert the boolean result with `NOT`

```
=NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP($A1,List!$A:$A,1,FALSE)))
```

Note: This is a `Classic > Formula` formatting rule, and the lookup value is $A1 because my "applies to" range starts on row 1 (and we always look at col A).

***Rule:***
[image: Formula]

***Formatting Range:***
[image: Applies to]

***Result:***
[image: Result]